# How do I turn on flashmode in Sony Ericsson Ray?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, rom-flashing

How do I turn on flashmode in sony xperia ray? I am doing what is said in forum the flash tool says I am in Fastboot mode not in flash mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT: Just try the combination with the other volume button if you enter the wrong mode (that's what I do because I cannot remember the button trick either and do trial&error every other time I need this.

Launch your software, prepare the ftf for flashing and *only* then do the following to enter **flash mode**:

- Switch off the phone (remove battery maybe)
- Press the **Volume down** button and hold it
- (While holding) Plug in the USB cable
- If successful, the LED should turn green

Just for the record, to enter **fastboot mode**:

- Switch off the phone (remove battery maybe)
- Press the **Volume up** button and hold it
- (While holding) Plug in the USB cable
- If successful, the LED should turn blue

If I mixed something up, please correct me.