# Get original xperia play content back on device after removing it

Tags: restore, operating-system, sony-ericsson-xperia-play

I've rooted my phone a while ago, deleted random apps I didn't really need that were pre installed. But now there's a potential buyer so I'd like to restore to the way it was the second I've brought it from the shop. Default factory reset didn't help as I've deleted games and stuff. So, is there a way to get everything back?

Comment: I'm assuming you didn't make a backup immediately after you rooted? If no, then you need to find an original image for the device and flash it using clockworkmod recovery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use their official update software, it has been called "PC Companion" the last time I used it:

- Boot your phone to flashmode (See also  [How do I turn on flashmode in Sony Ericsson Ray?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24960/how-do-i-turn-on-flashmode-in-sony-ericsson-ray))
- Update/restore it with [PC Companion](http://www.sonymobile.com/gb/software/phones/xperia-play/)

This is mostly for modding, so it won't be that useful to you:
You can also flash a .ftf file of your choice (official or a custom mod) with [FlashTool](http://androxyde.github.com/), note however that you need to [unlock the bootloader](http://unlockbootloader.sonymobile.com/) before your phone will boot a mod with an unoriginal kernel. I have however no idea where to find an original firmware image for your Xperia Play/R800i, you might need to google for that yourself.